# android - unique device ID

Tags: android

Yes I took a look at all similar questions, however I found no suitable answer. I need the device ID to set test devices for AdMob. My 1st approach (*some digits changed due to security reasons*):

```
  final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) c
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   Log.w("ID", tm.getDeviceId());
```

The result: `358948074051795`

Documentation says: *Returns the unique device ID, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not available.*

My 2nd approach:

```
   Log.w("ID_1",
            Secure.getString(c.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID));
```

The result: `98ade639139bf376`

Description: *A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated on the device's first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the device*

The question: what is the difference? Which one should I use for AdMob test purposes?

Comment: I hope you aren't posting the correct numbers for the results. Are you ?

Comment: "some digits changed due to security reasons"

Comment: LOL !! Glad you did !! :-D

Answer (score 1):

The difference is written in the descriptions of both methods...
However, I think using `IMEI number` is much more reliable because it identifies the device itself. What if the device has to restore default configuration ? 
You'd have to check if it doesn't generate a new number if you take your 2nd option.

More information about IMEI can be found here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity

Comment: yeah thanks, I know what IMEI is, just wondering what AdMod defines as "device ID"

Answer (score 1):

**1.Code**

```
Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID returns the Android ID as an unique 64-bit hex string

import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

String deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Toast.makeText(this, deviceId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**2.manifest**

Add **uses-permission** in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```